# Alterar código HTML via jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou tentando inserir o seguinte código [nesta página](https://www.naturalfitness.com.br/) para poder alterar o texto que aparece quando o cliente se inscreve no newsletter da modal, que aparece quando o cliente está prestes a sair da página:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-cadastre').on("click", function() {
        $('#modal_body_popup.modal-body-center .content-popup .newsletter-send').html('<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Cadastro realizado com sucesso. Compre qualquer produto, seu cupom da <strong>Corda de Pular</strong> está garantido até o final da compra.');
    });
});
```

Infelizmente, não sei por qual motivo, não está dando certo. Já tentei de várias formas e nada. Gostaria de uma ajuda pra poder resolver isso :)

PS.: estou usando o Tampermonkey v4.5 para fazer os testes.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro eu colocaria um alert dentro da função de click para verificar se está realmente entrando na função.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-cadastre').on("click", function() {
        alert("Entrou");
    });
});
```

Se estiver entrando na função é necessário checar se o seletor está correto. No seu caso tem o #modal_body_popup.modal-body-center que é pai de .content-popup que é pai de .newsletter-send (não necessariamente de 1º grau)

Se não estiver entrando na função e o seletor #btn-cadastre estiver mesmo correto talvez #btn-cadastre seja um item que foi inserido na página via javascript após a criação da sua função do click. Nesse caso uma das soluções é utilizar o "$(document).on":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#btn-cadastre", function() {
        $('#modal_body_popup.modal-body-center .content-popup .newsletter-send').html('<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Cadastro realizado com sucesso. Compre qualquer produto, seu cupom da <strong>Corda de Pular</strong> está garantido até o final da compra.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Eu fiz os testes se estava entrando na função, e não está. Infelizmente não tenho conhecimento avançado de jQuery para poder solucionar esse problema logo de cara. Mas tentei fazer da forma que me disse, usando o $(document).on e também não deu certo.

Comment: Acredito que o código que estou colocando, está vindo antes do código da modal inserido. Como pode ser contornado essa situação?

Comment: Nesse caso verifique o console do navegador em busca de erros de javascript. Clique em F12 e vá na aba Console. Cole aqui o erro, se houver

Comment: Lembrando que a biblioteca jquery deve estar referenciada para que os comandos funcionem

Comment: Infelizmente no console não tem erro. E a biblioteca já está referenciada, pois faço uso constante da biblioteca na página.

Comment: Fiz um teste inserindo o código no console após todo o carregamento da página e assim funciona. Então tentei fazer o uso do código após todo o carregamento da página, porém não deu certo. Nem com setTimeout